# How to check for existing records

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

Hi people am new to MVC3 and learning, I am wondering is it possible to allow the user on my website when they add a game to check if the game has allready been enterd. I want this feature so any gamer on my website can not write a overall review of the same game. The reason for this i have a page in which users can talke about the game. So that is why i want a way in checking the database when adding a new game that if the game exsits.

My controller is the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using PagedList;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO;
using Test.Models;

namespace Test.Controllers
{ 
    public class GameController : Controller
    {
        private gamezoneDBEntities db = new gamezoneDBEntities();

        //
        // GET: /Game/


        public ViewResult Index(string Ordering, string WordFilter, string DisplaySearchResults, int? CounterForPage)
        {

            {
                var Info = db.tblGames.Include(x => x.tblConsole);

            }

            var Games = from b in db.tblGames
            .Where(U => U.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
                        select b;


            switch (Ordering)
            {
                case "HeadlineName":
                    Games = Games.OrderBy(b => b.GameName);
                    break;
                case "DatePosted":
                    Games = Games.OrderBy(b => b.ReleaseYear);
                    break;
                case "DiscriptionDate":
                    Games = Games.OrderBy(b => b.ReleaseYear);
                    break;
                default:
                    Games = Games.OrderByDescending(b => b.ReleaseYear);
                    break;
            }

            int pageSize = 3;
            int pageNumber = (CounterForPage ?? 1);
            var PageNumberResults = Games.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
            ViewBag.PageNumberResults = Games.Count();
            if (PageNumberResults.Any())
            {
                return View(PageNumberResults);
            }

            return View("Error");
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(tblGame tblgame,
           HttpPostedFileBase image1,
           HttpPostedFileBase image2)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                    if (image1 != null)
                    {
                        string image = image1.FileName;
                        tblgame.Image = image;
                        var image1Path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadImages"), image);
                        image1.SaveAs(image1Path);
                    }

                    if (image2 != null)
                    {

                        string Image2 = image2.FileName;
                        tblgame.Image2 = Image2;
                        var image2Path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadImages"), Image2);
                        image2.SaveAs(image2Path);
                    }
                    db.tblGames.Add(tblgame);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                ViewBag.ConsoleNameIDFK = new SelectList(db.tblConsoles, "ConsoleName", "ConsoleName", tblgame.ConsoleNameIDFK);
                return View(tblgame);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View("Upload_Image_Failed");
            }

        }

        //
        // GET: /Game/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {

            ViewBag.ConsoleNameIDFK = new SelectList(db.tblConsoles, "ConsoleName", "ConsoleName");
            return View(new tblGame { UserName = @User.Identity.Name });

        } 



        public ViewResult Details(int id)
        {
            tblGame tblgame = db.tblGames.Find(id);
            return View(tblgame);
        }


        //
        // GET: /Game/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        { 
                tblGame tblgame = db.tblGames.Single(i => i.GameID == id);
                ViewBag.ConsoleNameIDFK = tblgame.ConsoleNameIDFK;
                return View(tblgame);
            }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(tblGame tblgame, HttpPostedFileBase Image, int id,
            HttpPostedFileBase image2)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {


                if (Image != null)
                {
                    string image = Image.FileName;
                    tblgame.Image = image;
                    var image1Path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadImages"), image);
                    Image.SaveAs(image1Path);
                }

                if (image2 != null)

                {

                    string Image2 = image2.FileName;
                    tblgame.Image2 = Image2;
                    var image2Path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadImages"), Image2);
                    image2.SaveAs(image2Path);
                }

                db.tblGames.Attach(tblgame);
                db.Entry(tblgame).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Edit");
            }

            ViewBag.ConsoleNameIDFK = new SelectList(db.tblConsoles, "ConsoleName", "ConsoleName", tblgame.ConsoleNameIDFK);
            return View(tblgame);
        }



        //
        // GET: /Game/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            tblGame tblgame = db.tblGames.Find(id);
            return View(tblgame);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Game/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)

        {
            try
            {

                tblGame tblgame = db.tblGames.Find(id);
                db.tblGames.Remove(tblgame);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View("Error");

            }
        }  


        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

I have had extermly hard time trying to see if game allreday exsits as i have code that makes users unique. I need this code otherwise I could have had a statment that checks the database for all games and throw an error if a game exsisted with this code i have added its a bit hard for me that is why i have come here.

I have added the following to my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(tblGame tblgame, HttpPostedFileBase image1, HttpPostedFileBase image2)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var mygame = db.tblGames.Where(x => x.GameName == tblgame.GameName).SingleOrDefault();
            if (mygame != null)
            {
                if (image1 != null)
                                {
                                    string image = image1.FileName;
                                    tblgame.Image = image;
                                    var image1Path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadImages"), image);
                                    image1.SaveAs(image1Path);
                                }

                                if (image2 != null)
                                {

                                    string Image2 = image2.FileName;
                                    tblgame.Image2 = Image2;
                                    var image2Path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadImages"), Image2);
                                    image2.SaveAs(image2Path);
                                }
                                db.tblGames.Add(tblgame);
                                db.SaveChanges();
                                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                //otherwise we add a generic error to the model state
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "A game review already exists");
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return View("Upload_Image_Failed");
    }
    //if arrive here the model is returned back to the view with the errors added
    return View(tblgame);
}
```

Comment: We need more people with enough reputation to approve your edit so that it shows on the page...

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Linq query to check if a game exists before saving.
Assuming in my example a field Name is enough to identify a game review you can do like that

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(tblGame tblgame, HttpPostedFileBase image1, HttpPostedFileBase image2)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
              var mygame = db.tblGames.Where(x => x.GameName == tblgame.GameName).SingleOrDefault();
              if (mygame != null)
              {
                if (image1 != null)
                {
                  string image = image1.FileName;
                  tblgame.Image = image;
                  var image1Path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadImages"), image);
                  image1.SaveAs(image1Path);
                }
                if (image2 != null)
                {
                  string Image2 = image2.FileName;
                  tblgame.Image2 = Image2;
                  var image2Path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadImages"), Image2);
                  image2.SaveAs(image2Path);
                }
                db.tblGames.Add(tblgame);
                db.SaveChanges();
                //All ok, we redirect to index or to Edit method. (PRG pattern)
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
              }
              else
              {
                //otherwise we add a generic error to the model state
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "A game review already exists");
              }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
          //return View("Upload_Image_Failed");
          ModelState.AddModelError("", "The upload of the images as failed");
        }
        //if we arrive here, the model is returned back to the view with the errors added
        ViewBag.ConsoleNameIDFK = new SelectList(db.tblConsoles, "ConsoleName", "ConsoleName", tblgame.ConsoleNameIDFK);
        return View(tblgame);
    }
```

Comment: Cant get it to complie with the code that i put on my edited question

Comment: I have tried your code, where you have put (x=>x.name = tblgame.Name) it was showing the following error: Does not contain a defintion of name, and i have changed it to "GameName" which is in my database and it still throws an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Comment: Ops my mistake. It's an equal condition so should be `==`. Updated

Comment: will try but my exsisting code that i have shown in my edited question where do i include that?

Comment: If I understand rght you should put the code of saving images and saving the entities instead of my comment "proceed with saving and other stuff". While you move the select list population just before the return View(tblgame) at the end of the method

Comment: The code complies but its not showing an error message, infact it allows the game to be enterd is the case senstive? do i have to use the exact spelling of the code?

Comment: try to put everthing lowercase or uppercase in the equals condition and see what happens

Comment: Can you no longer help me, on this matter i am really struggling

Comment: Looking at your edit it seems fine to me. the modelstate.addmodelerror add a generic message so in your view you should have a validation summary, maybe it's that why you don't see the message in the view

Comment: My validationmessagefor does exsist:

   <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GameName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GameName)
        </div>

Comment: I mean use [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationsummary.aspx](Html.ValidationSummary) to show generic error. thisi is used for error summary or for error not strictly coupled to a property

Comment: Cant view the link its no longer avaiable, could you not just show me what to do, cause this code am sure it works but i dont know how how. I have added it and when i fill all fields in it goes to the return View("Upload_Image_Failed");  and then when i fill a few fields in the application crashs an i get the following error on this: @Html.DropDownList("ConsoleNameIDFK", String.Empty) and the error is The ViewData item that has the key 'ConsoleNameIDFK' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.

Comment: That's error is because there is no Select list populated. the correct link is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationsummary.aspx). Updated answer

Comment: I have tried this, when all is blank then the message ModelState.AddModelError("", "A game review already exists");
pops up otherwise is allows it in but if i leave the image upload fields blank then it shows me ModelState.AddModelError("", "The upload of the images as failed");

Answer (score 1):

From the code you provided, you should change your `Create` action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(tblGame tblgame, // tblGame is the new game being created
       HttpPostedFileBase image1,
       HttpPostedFileBase image2)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
             /* Go to DB and check if there's a Game already there that matches this
                one just being added. What's the property you want to check against?
                That's something you must provide. I just wrote GameName to show you
                how to do this... */
             var game = db.tblGames.Single(g => g.GameName == tblGame.GameName);

             /* OK, can proceed adding this game... since there's no game in the DB
                that matches this one being added. */
             if (game == null)
             {
                // Continue saving the new game
             }
             else /* Abort and display a message to user informing that there's a game
                  already. */
             {
                // TODO
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cant get it to complie with the code i have put in my edited question

Comment: Yes this is because the code that i have just shown you in my edited question exsits therfore i cant combine them together which is giving the errors

Comment: If you can copy and paste the exact compile-time errors you are getting that would make it much easier for us to identity what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> I have had extermly hard time trying to see if game allreday exsits as
>   i have code that makes users unique. I need this code otherwise I
>   could have had a statment that checks the database for all games and
>   throw an error if a game exsisted with this code i have added its a
>   bit hard for me that is why i have come here.

With each user having their own unique game list, you would have a table called GameMapping something like this which maps each user to a game.

ID | UserID | GameID

ID is your auto-incremented, primary key. UserID would be a foreign key which links to the users primary ID, and GameID is a foreign key linking to a specific game.

```
var user = GetUser(); // not sure what you use to identity users, but that logic would go here
var game = Db.Games.Where(g => g.Name == tblGame.Name).First();

Db.GameMapping
   .Where(g => g.UserID == user.ID) // filter out all records for that user
   .Select(g => g.GameID) // select just the game IDs
   .Contains(game.ID) // see if the game id they want to add is in that list
```

---

Here is an alternative LINQ query which does the same check.

```
if (Db.GameMapping.Where(gm => gm.UserID == User.ID && gm.GameID == game.ID).Count() > 0)
     // user already has that game
else
     // they do not
```

---

It looks like the growth of your project is starting to introduce errors and become a bit overwhelming. What I would strongly suggest before implementing this game checking code in your project is to setup a small unit test first. Create a new project separate from your big project, add your database library and create a very small test where you enter in a game, and a user, and see if this code works as you expect it. Once you know your implementation is solid, then integrate it into the bigger project.

When you break the project into smaller pieces and test each piece you greatly reduce the complexity of debugging the entire thing. Good Luck.